# Ignore existing haml-lint violations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, haml-lint

How do I ask haml-lint to create a configuration file for ignoring existing violations? Something equivalent to the `--auto-gen-config` option for RuboCop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called `.haml-lint.yml` in your project directory.  A default `.haml-lint.yml` file looks like:

```
# Default application configuration that all configurations inherit from.
#
# This is an opinionated list of which hooks are valuable to run and what their
# out of the box settings should be.

# Whether to ignore frontmatter at the beginning of HAML documents for
# frameworks such as Jekyll/Middleman
skip_frontmatter: false

linters:
  AltText:
    enabled: false

  ClassAttributeWithStaticValue:
    enabled: true

  ClassesBeforeIds:
    enabled: true

  ConsecutiveComments:
    enabled: true

  ConsecutiveSilentScripts:
    enabled: true
    max_consecutive: 2

  EmptyScript:
    enabled: true

  FinalNewline:
    enabled: true
    present: true

  HtmlAttributes:
    enabled: true

  ImplicitDiv:
    enabled: true

  LeadingCommentSpace:
    enabled: true

  LineLength:
    enabled: true
    max: 80

  MultilinePipe:
    enabled: true

  MultilineScript:
    enabled: true

  ObjectReferenceAttributes:
    enabled: true

  RuboCop:
    enabled: true
    # These cops are incredibly noisy when it comes to HAML templates, so we
    # ignore them.
    ignored_cops:
      - Lint/BlockAlignment
      - Lint/EndAlignment
      - Lint/Void
      - Metrics/LineLength
      - Style/AlignParameters
      - Style/BlockNesting
      - Style/FileName
      - Style/FinalNewline
      - Style/IfUnlessModifier
      - Style/IndentationWidth
      - Style/Next
      - Style/TrailingBlankLines
      - Style/TrailingWhitespace
      - Style/WhileUntilModifier

  RubyComments:
    enabled: true

  SpaceBeforeScript:
    enabled: true

  SpaceInsideHashAttributes:
    enabled: true
    style: space

  Indentation:
    enabled: true
    character: space # or tab

  TagName:
    enabled: true

  TrailingWhitespace:
    enabled: true

  UnnecessaryInterpolation:
    enabled: true

  UnnecessaryStringOutput:
    enabled: true
```

See the official [documentation](https://github.com/brigade/haml-lint#configuration) for further details.